# how to set datasource to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu, datasource

I want to add a datasource to a dropdownlist. This dropdownlist is one of the columns of a gridview. Here I want to add a datasource to the dropdownlist dynamically without using the sqldatasource.

(vs2008 and c#)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the OnDataBinding event for the dropdownlist control in your grid.  In the event you could assign the DataSource property and other attributes to whatever you like.  Bind it to a `List<YourObject>` even.

Doing it on the OnDataBinding event also allows you to customize the values in the ddl on the fly as well.  So each row's ddl could have a different set of options available based on some other data in your row if you need that type of functionality.

Tons of flexability with the ASP.NET controls if the OnDataBinding method is used instead of the auto (easy mode) wire ups.

Comment: pls tell me i set datasource like OnDataBinding event
            DropDownList11.DataSource = dataTable;
            DropDownList11.DataValueField = "ProjectCode";
            DropDownList11.DataTextField = "ProjectCode";
            DropDownList11.DataBind();
but the error will occur like 
the name "DropDownList11" does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

yes as it is in the itemtemplate so you wont get it directly for that you have to use findcontrol

Answer (score 0):

Here is the codes you are looking for

**Example 1 :**

```
public enum Color
{
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE
}
```

Every Enum type derives from System.Enum. There are two static methods that help bind data to a drop-down list control (and retrieve the value). These are Enum.GetNames and Enum.Parse. Using GetNames, you are able to bind to your drop-down list control as follows:

```
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList ddColor;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        ddColor.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Color));
        ddColor.DataBind();
     }
}
```

**Example 2 :**

```
List<Person> myPList = new List<Person>();



Person p1 = new Person();

p1.ID = 1;

p1.Name = "Bob";

p1.Color = "Blue";



Person p2 = new Person();

p2.ID = 2;

p2.Name = "Joe";

p2.Color = "Green";



myPList.Add(p1);

myPList.Add(p2);



this.DropDownList1.DataSource = myPList;

this.DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Color";

this.DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";

this.DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

for a more complete practice look at here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076237/132239

*also don't forget always to mark your answers as an answer*