# how to fill DropDownList from database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

how to fill DropDownList from database in asp.net ?

and when i pick value from the DropDownList how to catch this event ?

```
Conn.Open();
SQL = "SELECT distinct city FROM MEN";
dsView = new DataSet();
adp = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
adp.Fill(dsView, "MEN");
adp.Dispose();

DropDownList1. ?????? (what do to ?)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You set the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource.aspx), [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) and [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) and call [`DataBind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd7t67ef.aspx) in order to populate the dropdownlist.

The datasource can be pretty much any `IEnumerable` and the text and value will be looked up with reflection.

The event you want to catch is the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event - this will fire when you change the selection.

Comment: @Gold - Most of the links have examples.

Answer (score 3):

First take the details in a dataset
    then the following code will help you:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = ds
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "emailid"
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "userid"
DropDownList1.DataBind()
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("select", "-1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple sample code :

```
DropDownList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
DropDownList.DataTextField = "displayNameColumnName ";
DropDownList.DataValueField = "TheValueColumnName";
DropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a complete walkthrough for you in this case :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDropDownLists();
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

        SqlDataSource sqlDS = new SqlDataSource();
        sqlDS.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ToString();
        sqlDS.SelectCommand = "select GenderID,Gender from mylookupGender";
        form1.Controls.Add(sqlDS);

        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = "dddlGender";
        ddl.DataSource = sqlDS;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Gender";
        ddl.DataValueField = "GenderID";
        form1.Controls.Add(ddl);

        // ... Repeat above code 9 times or put in a for loop if they're all the same...
}

private void BindDropDownLists()
{
    foreach (Control ctl in form1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl is DropDownList)
        {
            (ctl as DropDownList).DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//...Wrote separate class for calling this function
FunctionClass obj = new FunctionClass();
List<Designation> details = new List<Designation>();
bool result1 = obj.DataDrop(out details);
if (result1 == true)
{
dropDownDesignation.DataSource = details;
dropDownDesignation.DataTextField = "designation";
dropDownDesignation.DataValueField = "Designation_ID";
dropDownDesignation.DataBind();
dropDownDesignation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}

//..This function wrote inside FunctionClass and called from aspx.cs page
public bool DataDrop(out List<Designation> designationDetails)
{
designationDetails = new List<Designation>();
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionName);
conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "DesignationDetails";
userReader = command.ExecuteReader();
if(userReader.HasRows)
{
    while(userReader.Read())
{
    designationDetails.Add(new Designation()
    {
            designationId=userReader.GetInt32(0),
            designation=userReader.GetString(1)
        });
 }
}
return true;
}
//..This should declare outside the class but inside the namespace
public class Designation
{
public int designationId { get; set; }
public string designation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to bind dropdownlist is...

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" DataValueField="pkId" DataTextField="cityName" DataSourceID="sqlDB">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDB" ConnectionString='$Name of connecitonstring' runat="server" SelectCommand="Select * from tbl_City"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```